# How to pass a string as a generic in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typescript-generics

I want to create a generic type that I can use to transform normal type into a type that complies with my API response structure. So the issue is that I have bunch of types and I want to infer off of them another bunch of types that will be look something like this:

```
// this is a type that i have
interface IModel {
  key1: string
  key2: string
}

//this is a type I want to infer
interface IModelResponse {
  model: {
    key1: string
    key2: string
  }
}

// the way i want to do this is through generics in TypeScript
// so let's say something like this:
type IModelResponse = IBaseResponse<IModel, 'model'>
```

I tried something like this:

```
export interface IBaseResponse<T, modelName extends string> {
  [key: modelName]: T
}
```

but it gives me an error "An index signature parameter type must be either 'string' or 'number'."

is there something i don't get, or is this impossible to implement in the way that I intend? Would appreciate some help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be implemented using the *`in`* keyword

```
interface IModel {
  key1: string
  key2: string
}

type BaseResponse<T, ModelName extends string> = {
  [key in ModelName]: T
}

type IModelResponse = BaseResponse<IModel, 'model'>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Now can you detail a little bit further why does it work or maybe point me in the direction where I can read more about this behaviour

Comment: The syntax of { [key: string] } is limited to two common values `string` and `number`. No more, no less. Using `in`, you can specify narrower sets of values as keys (in particular, literals). https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html